# Read text file - and export part of text line

Tags: text

I'm trying to extract some data from a text file.
Functions I use ( as grep ) extract entire line as an answer, but I need to get a specific portion of the text line out to another file.

for example: a text file contains :
" On Tuesdays- I go running On Wednesdays- I go to the GYM on 5th AVE"

I wish to seek where I go on Wednesdays ( for example using grep ), but to extract only the part " I go to the GYM" and direct it to a new file

Comment: Could you be more specific? Give a clear example please.

Comment: `grep` has a `-o` flag to return only the matched portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `-o` flag (only) to export only desired text and regex to match variable text after "I go to". So, in your case the command would be

`cat text| grep -o "I go to the [aA-zZ]*`

where `grep -o` matches only desired text and regex `[aA-zZ]*` matches any single word after that.

If you want to filter different days, you can add another grep in the middle, e.g.

`cat text| grep "Wed" | grep -o "I go to the [aA-zZ]*`

For simple guide to regex in grep see 
[beginners-guide-gnu-grep-basics-regular-expressions/](http://opensourceforu.com/2012/06/beginners-guide-gnu-grep-basics-regular-expressions/)

Comment: Instead of multiple greps, you could use PCRE mode with a perl-style `\K` to discard the prefix: `grep -Po 'On Wednesdays- \KI go to the [aA-zZ]*' file`. Note that `grep` doesn't need `cat` in either case.